# Excel 2016 Trying to copy one cell to another is just putting the formula in the cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to copy the text in a cell on one sheet (Sage Issues) to a cell on another sheet (Alternatives). This is the current formula in a cell on the "Alternatives" sheet that is just putting the formula in the cell. It isn't copying the merged cells B6-I6 on the "Sage Issues" page, it is just writing the formula to the cell.

='Sage Issues'!B6

The cells on the "Sage Issues" sheet are merged. Both the target cells and the new cells are formatted as General.

All the research I have done says that the formula should copy the text from those cells on the first sheet into the new cells on the new sheet, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the cell and right click the cell you want to paste to and select paste special. This will bring up a menu to select the "values" option.

This can also be done through navigating the right-click menu, but I never select the correct option.

Comment: That isn't updating the values in real time though, it just does a static copy. I need it to be able to update the values in the formula cells if I change the master cell. Thanks for the assistance though.